# Which features should I consider, other than encryption and data security, when choosing to buy a VPN service for longer period?

Tags: security, vpn, encryption, privacy

I wanted to know about features that makes a VPN worth buying. My main purpose of using a VPN is privacy and online security, but I want to get suggestions about other features that different service providers are offering. I did read about PureVPN, Express VPN, Ivacy VPN and Hide My Ass on multiple websites but all of these reviews and information have got me confused. It will be great if anyone can help me critically evaluating the features and suggesting which is better, as I will be needing my subscription for a longer period of time.

To eleborate my concern, I want to stay anonymous and secure from any online threats or third party monitoring. One of my uses is that I want to access my credit card online from a different country. I hope now that my question is better!

Comment: Your question tries to match *privacy and online security* against *features* without defining any of these. In security the first question to ask is always "What do you want to defend against?". Asking us to list and evaluate available *features* is too broad.

Comment: Questions seeking opionionated answers are not on topic here at Superuser

Comment: Edit: To eleborate my concern, I want to stay anonymous and secure from any online threats or third party monitoring. One of my uses is that I want to access my credit card online from different country. Hope now my question is better!

Answer (score 0):

You want a VPN that has these features:

- A good reputation (a VPN that has no record of giving out user's
  information)
- Good speeds
- Anonymous DNS servers (this is very important as far as anonymity
  goes)
- At least promises not to keep records

Other than that, there's not much else you want from a VPN

Personally, I favour Cyberghost for all of this, and I'd suggest using it, but the choice, of course, is up to you.